# What is the chemical composition of Turnbull's blue?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, precipitation

I was studying qualitative analysis from this book and  I found some tests for testing the presence of the cation $\ce{Fe^{++}}$.

There was a test in which we add $\ce{K4[Fe(CN)6]}$ solution to a solution of a ferrous salt which results in the Turnbull blue precipitate. Now according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussian_blue#Turnbull.27s_blue), the Turnbull blue and Prussian blue are the same compound, ie, ferriferrocyanide $\left(\ce{Fe4[Fe(CN)6]3} \right)$.

But the book says that Turnbull blue is ferroferricyanide $\left(\ce{Fe3[Fe(CN)6]2}\right)$ which kinda makes sense because we are adding ferricyanide to ferrous solution.

I am preparing for an exam in which such questions can be asked SO I just want to settle this once and for all, which is wrong, Wikipedia or the book?

Comment: see also: Hansen, L. D.; Litchman, W. M.; Daub, G. H. Turnbull’s blue and Prussian blue: KFe(III)[Fe(II)(CN)6]. _J. Chem. Educ.,_ **1969,** _46_ (1), 46; http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ed046p46

Comment: @Loong the link is good but what about user104014's answer? Can we say that the equilibrium hugely favours the formation of prussian blue?

Comment: **Update**: I have asked ["What is the chemical composition of Ferrous Ferrocyanide?"](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/157652/what-is-the-chemical-composition-of-ferrous-ferrocyanide)

Answer (score 6):

Though your textbook is right, Wikipedia isn't completely wrong as in aqueous solution, $\left(\ce{Fe3[Fe(CN)6]2} \right)$ gets converted and is in equilibrium with $\left(\ce{Fe4[Fe(CN)6]3} \right)$ (a redox change) and hence prussian blue and turnbull's blue are identical to look visually. But in a textual way, the naming is given as your textbook says, *i.e.* $\left(\ce{Fe4[Fe(CN)6]3} \right)$ is Prussian blue whereas $\left(\ce{Fe3[Fe(CN)6]2} \right)$ is Turnbull's blue.